# Control duplicado en primefaces

Tags: java, primefaces, programación-móvil

Estoy trabajando con primefaces y he creado un login donde selecciono a que base de datos me conectare ya que tengo varias dependiendo de la eleccion asi inicializo la conexion, pero el problema es a nivel de la vista que el control me aparece como triplicado en el navegador, no se a que se debera si me faltara una libreria o que problema pueda ser
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"  
      contentType="text/html">

    <f:view renderKitId="PRIMEFACES_MOBILE" />
    <h:head />

    <h:body>
        <pm:page title="Login" loadingMessage="Cargando...">
            <pm:header title=" Mobile" />

            <pm:content>
                <h:form id="login_frm">
                    <p:remoteCommand  name="loadBD"
                                      process="@this"
                                      async="true"
                                      autoRun="true"
                                      update="somBD" 
                                      action="#{loginBean.loadBD()}" />

                    <p:growl id="messageError" for="msgError" showDetail="true" widgetVar="messageError" showSummary="true" />

                    <p:panel header="Login" >
                        <p:inputText label="Usuario: * " widgetVar="username" id="username" value="#{loginBean.username}" required="true" styleClass="input" title="#{component.valid ? '' : 'El Código de usuario no puede ir vacío'}" />
                        <pm:field>
                            <p:outputLabel for="password" value="Contraseña " styleClass="label"/>  
                            <p:password id="password" label="Contraseña" value="#{loginBean.password}" redisplay="true" required="true" styleClass="password" title="#{component.valid ? '' : 'Debe de introducir un password para ingresar al sistema'}" />
                        </pm:field>
                        <pm:field>
                            <h:outputLabel for="somBD" value="Empresa: "/>
                            <h:selectOneMenu id="somBD" value="#{loginBean.idbd}" > 
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione..." itemDisabled="true" itemValue="#{null}" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{loginBean.l_bases_de_datos}" var="bd" itemLabel="#{bd.nombrebd}" itemValue="#{bd.idbd}"/>  
                            </h:selectOneMenu>
                        </pm:field>

                        <p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.validUser}" value="Ingresar" styleClass="button-primary" update=":login_frm:messageError" process="@form" />
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </pm:content>
        </pm:page>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Necesitamos que nos muestres tu codigo de la vista para que podamos ver por donde va el problema

Comment: Olvide colocar el codigo perdon ya esta actualizado

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de usar `<h:selectOneMenu>` y no un control de primefaces?

Comment: Segun vi en la documentacion de primefaces ese es el control para el dropdownlist https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Comment: @Chris pero nos seria `<p:selectOneMenu>` ?? en lugar de con `h`

Comment: Ya hice ese cambio tambien pero siempre se mantiene el problema

Comment: Qué versión de prime faces estás usando?

Comment: La version 0.9.3

Comment: Necesitas subir tu controlador. pero alguno de los errores que veo es que no necesitas deshabilitar tu selectOneMenu (ItemDisable), esto se usa cuando alguna de las elementos a mostrar quieres que se deshabiliten pero para ello necesitas un método desde tu controlador que haga eso y la expresión de tu itemValue la estas inicializando en "null".